# How do you choose when to show the "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" notice?

Tags: support, comments, chat, comment-to-chat-migration

I have answered two questions:

- [Angularjs:How to remove dynamical table row, but no remove from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893009/angularjshow-to-remove-dynamical-table-row-but-no-remove-from-array/36893451#36893451)
- [Infinite scroll repeate same id again from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913943/infinite-scroll-repeate-same-id-again-from-database/36914466#36914466)

On the first one we've posted 12 comments, and on the second one only 7.

But - Why am I only getting the **Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?** notice in the SECOND answer, while the first one has more comments?

Comment: Related: [Where's the auto-move-to-chat link?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10691) (answered by a member of staff)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my own observation, this appears when the system detects a "dialogue" between two users, where each side posts at least four comments, and the other side replies:

> [image]

Comment: Oh ... you count me!

Comment: Also, first FHRC is probably wrong. There's no discussion with you yet.

Comment: @alexolut the system doesn't really look for comment replies, any comment counts. That was the first comment in the "dialogue" between us. :-)

Comment: For me ([on ruSO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0LkV.png)) it's appeared after 3 comments.