# Is there a network-wide policy on what constitutes an "extended discussion" in comments and why they're a bad idea?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-to-chat-migration

I've seen a number of Meta discussion on various sites on exactly what constitutes an "extended discussion" and the extent to which they should (or shouldn't) be tolerated.

Is there a network-wide policy about extended discussions in comments, or is it site-by-site policy?

Is there some "official" definition of what constitutes an extended discussion that could be applied across multiple sites?

Also, why are extended discussions in comments considered harmful in the first place? (I'm particularly interested in what the original rationale was for implementing this policy, but general feedback on why extended discussion in comments is considered harmful now would definitely be helpful as well).

Comment: Are you specifically talking about comments on Meta sites? Because the rules on meta are somewhat different as it relates to comments.

Comment: related: [Moving comments to chat: is it just about length?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279448/165773) Speaking of harm, to me it seems two-fold. First, comments discussions tend to obscure answers which are "real units of work" as Atwood calls them. And second, it is harmful for the very discussion because of comments UI "there's that thing about collapsed comments chains that nothing can fix - it's when you _expand_ them. It is actually the moment when it becomes apparent how bad they fit into UI. Watching and following 30... 40... 100 comments exploded... "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments are *meant* to be temporary - they're meant to suggest improvements (which might not be on scope for an edit) or clarifications. Conversations in comments are often *noise* and *noise is harmful*.

The extended discussion nag is automatic, and network wide.

On the other hand, chat's better if you need an extended back and forth conversation. It has replies, which makes it easier to keep track of things.

So, extended discussion in comments are roughly as harmful as using a spanner to drive in nails. You might get the nails in, or accidentally bean yourself or your cat in the head in the process. You're much better off using a hammer for the job.

Also, apparently people remove nails you're driven in with a spanner and don't always drive them back in with a hammer - but this is where my metaphor breaks down.

Comment: Is there a widely-accepted definition of what constitutes an "extended discussion"?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278872/135565 describes the logic used

Comment: IMHO the logic of this is a bit overreaching: "conversations in comments are often noise; noise is bad --> conversations in comments are bad". What about conversations in comments that are additive and useful?  I just got 3 sets of comments removed. Two were deleted entirely, one was moved to chat, where nobody pays attention anymore, effectively [killing the conversation entirely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345347/add-pings-to-moved-to-chat-comments).

Comment: Except, chat doesn't work. I don't know exactly why, but 90% of the time the participants in the discussion (even if the discussion is relevant to suggesting improvements to the question) simply never access the chat.